# RabbitMQ x-max-length-bytes Argument Not Working

Tags: rabbitmq

[image: Max Length = 1MB, Queue Size: 412MB]

All,
I'm playing around with the parameters of RabbitMQ queues trying to limit growth. I have noticed that the x-max-length parameter works as expected, but when I change to x-max-length bytes, this does not.

See my example below, where we see the argument correctly listed for the queue, but you can see the unbounded growth happening and a memory footprint for the queue of 421MB while I had it set to just 1MB.

Any ides on why this is happening?

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: What is total size of messages bodies in queue? `x-max-length-bytes` takes effect on total bodies size.